# Permission Error using SQL Server and Integrated Security

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, windows-server-2012

I have a windows service (.NET) that is running with as a domain user, which has full permissions on needed database resources and filesystem. The service calls a procedure which invokes a bulk insert statement in SQL Server.

The service is run with integrated security, the account has been granted login as service rights. However, I am facing a permission issue when the service runs in a different server other than where the SQL Server is located.

The app Server is called Srv01, and db server is Sql01. The process generates pdf and calls bulk insert using a procedure in Sql01. When I install the windows service in Srv01, I get the following error:

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "//Srv01/Output/Letter.pdf" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
```

The network share has full permissions for Everyone. I am just trying to get this to work and tighten security later.

When I run the same service, with the same domain user in the same server as the database, namely Sql01, the process works correctly.

We are running: Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2012 Enterprise, and the service is written in .NET 4.5. I have tried looking into the local security policies on both sql server and app server, but without any results. Yes, I've restarted the app server too (not the db though).

Comment: Looks like a double hop problem: authentication from srv01 to sql01 works, but when sql01 attempts to impersonate the account to access the share on srv01 it fails. There's plenty of things that can go wrong here; [this site](https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2009/05/22/microsoft-sql-2005-bulk-insert-kerberos-double-hop-and-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied/) describes one scenario in detail.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert. That article was useful, but the forums it was pointing to were unreachable. I eventually figured it out! It was related to Service Principal Names and Kerberos Auth. I will write a bigger entry as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, and I will share the following findings:

1. Install the Kerberos Configuration Tool for SQL Server 2012 and ensure all SPNs are configured correctly. URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046
   If this tool gives you any errors when connecting to the SQL Server, check local groups (probably Administrators), you may have a removed user appearing with as a UUID, and remove it. Restart the tool and fix any problems.
2. Configure SPN for the windows service. The syntax is:

   setspn -a [service_class]/[FQDN]:port DOMAIN_NAME\domain_user

   Note that you must use the FQDN in the network, IP only does not work. The port is optional. Also, from `[service_class]` can only be from a selected keyword list. List is found here:
   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772815(WS.10).aspx
   (credit goes to:
   https://serverfault.com/questions/350782/can-someone-please-explain-windows-service-principle-names-spns-without-oversi)

   In my case, I used the http server class (why? no reason! a custom service class didn't work for me)

   setspn -a http/Srv01.mydomain.com MYDOMAIN\myuser
3. Next go to the Active Directory's properties of both users SQL Server domain user, and Windows Service domain user. Go in the Delegation tab, and "Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)".
4. Finally, restart windows service (I restarted the SQL Server service just to be certain). Monitor the connections from the server where the service is installed with:

   select session_id,net_transport,client_net_address,auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections
   WHERE client_net_address = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'

You should see Kerberos for connections coming from the application server. This resolved the issue with file permissions as well.